# Draw horizontal or vertical lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, vertical

I create a new shapefile layer as a line. Then I activated editing mode and want to draw vertical or horizontal lines with add feature but holding shift does not allow to draw a horizontal or vertical line (I used QGIS 2.14.4).

How can I draw horizontal or vertical lines as a shapefile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CADTools plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cadtools/) has a feature named `Orthogonal Digitizing`.

While in editing mode of a line or polygon layer, holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> allows to draw orthogonal lines.

Furthermore, the QAD plugin snaps to the horizontal or vertical axis when drawing a `LINE` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to draw a grid you can use the Create Grid algorithm (see: https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/creategrid.html).
For arbitrary horizontal lines you can use the Numerical Digitize Plugin, giving the same value for the north coordinate.