# Is there a keyboard shortcut to draw a perftectly straight line?

Tags: qgis, line, tools, shortcuts

In most programs, when you have a line tool, you can hold control or shift and it will let you draw a perfectly vertical or horizontal line, sometimes it the tool will snap at 90 degree angles. How would I go about doing this in QGIS?

Comment: In QGIS 2.x, you can use the CADTools plugin as explained here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208569/draw-horizontal-or-vertical-lines-in-qgis

Comment: Note that "vertical" and "horizontal" only hold true within a single projection. A line that is perfectly vertical in one projection will be askew in a different projection.